# The selected device was disconnected and cannot be accessed anymore from this machine

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, rider

I am trying to run my Xamarin app in debug mode on an iPhone 11. But I'm getting a "cannot be accessed" error.

[image: iPhone 11 connection error message]

And when I attempt to open the simulator I get the following error.

[image: Simulator error message]

I've upgraded to the latest version of Rider (`2020.2.3`) but I'm still getting the issue. Why can't I run my app on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install additional XCode components—likely because of a recent MacOS update. Do the following:

1. Open XCode

[image]

2. Click "Install" when prompted

[image]

Once the components have been installed, you should be able to run your app on an iPhone.

[image]

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Thank you @JackHua-MSFT. I will definitely mark this as the accepted answer when Stack Overflow allows me tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but nothing was updated on my machine. I ended up rebooting my iPhone, which fixed the problem for me.